# Echo hash only from shasum

Tags: hashsum

Is there a way to get `shasum` to *only* print the hash?

I know this can be achieved by piping the output to another program, e.g.

```
shasum something | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Is there a way to achieve this only using `shasum`, without having to pipe the result somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

No. As of Perl shasum 6.02 and the corresponding programs in GNU coreutils 9.1, there is no way to print just the hexadecimal representation of the hash without a file name (which can be `-` for standard input).

But don't let this be a problem! The shell is designed to combine multiple programs and [pipes are a fundamental feature of the shell](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Ehos/frs122/precis/mcilroy.htm). You just need to be careful not to swallow the error — this is a design defect with sh pipes.

In plain sh, it's actually easier to use a “hidden” pipe via a command substitution, rather than a shell pipeline.

```
out=$(shasum <something) && echo "${out%%[!0-9A-Za-z]*}"
```

Explanation: The first part of the command (before `&&`) sets `out` to the output of `shasum`. Since it's a simple assignment, its status is the status of the single command substitution, so it fails if `shasum` fails. The `&&` operator ensures that if the left-hand side fails, the whole command fails. If the left-hand side succeeds, the right-hand side prints the leading alphanumerical characters of the output. (`… && echo "${out%% *}"` would work too, the version above is slightly more robust in case a future version uses a tab for example.)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas No, you're right, there isn't. `shasum` is a perl script that has command line options modelled on GNU coreutils.

Comment: Note that [`pipefail` will be a standard `sh` option in the next versions of the standard](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=789) and is already supported by many `sh` implementations.

Answer (score 1):

No, `shasum` always prints the filename of the file that it computes the hash for, or `-` if it reads from standard input.

To avoid the pipe, you could use

```
perl -MDigest::SHA -e '$s=Digest::SHA->new(); $s->add(<>); print $s->hexdigest(),"\n"' filename
```

Comment: Note that the code posted here completely ignores errors. For example it will happily print a checksum and return 0 if the specified file doesn't exist. This is an annoyance with perl for system programming.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, the ast-open of `sha1sum` (or `cksum -x sha1`) which can also be the `sha1sum` builtin of `ksh93` if built as part of ast-open (enabled there with `builtin sha1sum` or by putting `/opt/ast/bin` ahead of `$PATH`), or the `sha1` utility as found for instance on FreeBSD, only prints the checksum when summing stdin.

So, with those implementation, you can just do:

```
sha1sum < thefile
sha1 < thefile
```

```
$ ./ast-open/arch/linux.i386-64/bin/ksh
$ builtin sha1sum
$ whence -a sha1sum
sha1sum is a shell builtin
sha1sum is a shell builtin version of /usr/bin/sha1sum
$ echo test | sha1sum
4e1243bd22c66e76c2ba9eddc1f91394e57f9f83
$ echo test | /usr/bin/sha1sum
4e1243bd22c66e76c2ba9eddc1f91394e57f9f83  -
```

`openssl sha1` can also print the checksum raw, which you can convert to hex with `hexdump -e '20/1 "%02x" "\n"'` or `xxd -p` for instance:

```
openssl sha1 -binary -- "$file" | xxd -p
```

The GNU implementation of `sha1sum` outputs `<thehexsum>  -` (the second space possibly replaced with `*` to indicate *binary mode* on MSDOS-like systems), same for the `shasum` utility shipped with `perl`.  `openssl sha1` outputs `(stdin)= <thehexsum>`, `openssl sha1 -r` (`-r` meant to emulate GNU coreutils format) outputs `<thehexsum> *stdin`

So, as already said, with those, you'd have to extract the checksum from that:

```
sha1sum < "$file" | awk '{print $1}'
```

(with `set -o pipefail` beforehand where supported to preserve `sha1sum` (or file input redirection) failure if any)

Or, in POSIX-like shells:

```
sum=$(sha1sum < "$file") && sum=${sum%%[[:space:]]*}
```

`[[:space:]]*` can also be replaced with `[![:xdigit:]]*` to remove everything starting with the first character that is not a hexadecimal digit.

Answer (score -1):

**You can use `cut` command anyway**

1. without piping into cut

```
$ sha256sum ~/hwinfo.txt
d7e1653cc9e37552a70a9daebefdc3bc25949a691086cd325d071a98dfc105aa  /home/user/hwinfo.txt
```

2.piping into `cut` while using space as a delimetere

```
$ sha256sum ~/hwinfo.txt | cut -d" " -f 1
d7e1653cc9e37552a70a9daebefdc3bc25949a691086cd325d071a98dfc105aa
```

---

**There are 3 fields**

field 1 is sha256sum

```
$ sha256sum ~/hwinfo.txt | cut -d" " -f 1
d7e1653cc9e37552a70a9daebefdc3bc25949a691086cd325d071a98dfc105aa
```

field 2 is empty because here nothing is in between two spaces

```
$ sha256sum ~/hwinfo.txt | cut -d" " -f 2
```

field 3 is the file name

```
$ sha256sum ~/hwinfo.txt | cut -d" " -f 3
/home/user/hwinfo.txt
```

Comment: If you do string processing on the output, counting the characters is a really bad way to do it. Just take all the characters up to the first space. This does use a pipe though (not a shell pipeline, but the command substitution does use a pipe).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).