# Visible content of 2 variables in bash is the same, but the length is different

Tags: bash, terminal

These 2 variables will have the same visible content

```
  x_sign1="aabbccdd_and_somthing_else"

  var1="...."
  [........]
  x_sign2=$(echo -n "${var1}${var2}${var3}" | shasum -a 256)
  echo $x_sign2

  ====> 
  aabbccdd_and_somthing_else -
```

Note the "-" in the end.

However, their lengths will be different. Even though the `x_sign2` doesn't contain a new line symbol. To ensure this:

```
  x_sign22=$(echo -n "${var1}${var2}${var3}" | shasum -a 256 | tr -d '\n')
```

But:

```
  echo ${#x_sign1}
  ====> 64
  And:
```

And:

```
  echo ${#x_sign2}

  ====> 67

  echo ${#x_sign22}

  ====> 67
```

The difference is 3 symbols. The visible content is identical.

Also, when I make a request via curl to a REST API which needs that value of a signature, `x_sign1` always succeeds, whereas `x_sign2` doesn't -- "wrong signature"

Why? How to fix that?

Comment: Possibly related: [Echo hash only from shasum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400292/echo-hash-only-from-shasum)

Comment: @steeldriver I'm not asking how to calculate hash

Comment: But you do seem to be asking why the result has three extra characters, and how to remove them

Comment: @steeldriver yes, but your link suggests perl

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo foo |shasum -a 256
b5bb9d8014a0f9b1d61e21e796d78dccdf1352f23cd32812f4850b878ae4944c  -    
                                                                ^^
```

Note that there are *two* spaces in the output of `shasum` before the filename. When the input is taken from stdin, `shasum` prints a dash as the filename.

If you run `echo foo | shasum | od -c` you can check that, and see the newline at the end also. The newline, however, is removed by the command substitution, so removing it explicitly with `tr` doesn't do anything. (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17747/170373) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/383217/170373))

The two spaces and the dash are three characters that cause the difference in your counts.

To get just the hash, you could use parameter expansions to remove anything after the first space, e.g.:

```
$ h=$(echo foo | shasum -a 256)
$ h=${h%% *}
$ printf ">%s<\n" "$h"
>b5bb9d8014a0f9b1d61e21e796d78dccdf1352f23cd32812f4850b878ae4944c<
```

The `${var%%pattern}` expands to the value of `var` with the longest suffix matching `pattern` removed.

Comment: how did those 2 whitespaces and the dash end up in the variable?

Comment: @Immani because that's the default behavior when `shasum` reads from standard input instead of a named file

Comment: @steeldriver how to get rid of them?

Comment: @Immani, edited

Comment: what are `>`, `\n` and `<` for?

Comment: @Immani `><` are there just to show that there's no newline in the variable. `\n` is the final newline to be printed at the end of that string.